# Declaring minimal width of serie in treemap

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jsfiddle, treemap

I have treemap chart and it has two values Squadra2 with value of 13778.00 and Squadra1 with value of 16.00
Now when treemap renders it takes percentage difference between them and split them accordingly BUT now I ended up in situation where I need to be sniper precise in order to select Squadra1 with value of 16.00
As you can see in the picture
[image]

Is there a possibility to declare for example minimal width of Squadra1, and to disallow it to go under that value ( to remain clickable ) ?
Please let me know, thank you

```
    {
  "chart": {
  renderTo:"container",
    "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
  },
  "colorAxis": {
    "labels": {
      "enabled": false
    },
    "tickLength": 0,
    "gridLineWidth": 0,
    "min": 0,
    "max": 20,
    "stops": [
      [
        -0.001,
        "#ffffff"
      ],
      [
        0.5,
        "#7cb5ec"
      ],
      [
        0.501,
        "#7cb5ec"
      ],
      [
        0.499,
        "#ffffff"
      ],
      [
        1,
        "#434348"
      ],
      [
        1.001,
        "#434348"
      ]
    ]
  },
  "legend": {
    "enabled": true,
    "itemStyle": {
      "color": "#FFF"
    }
  },
  "tooltip": {},
  "series": [
    {
      "drillUpButton": {
        "position": {
          "align": "center",
          "verticalAlign": "bottom"
        },
        "theme": {
          "fill": "white",
          "stroke-width": 1,
          "stroke": "silver",
          "r": 2,
          "style": {
            "fontSize": "12px"
          },
          "states": {
            "hover": {}
          }
        }
      },
      "type": "treemap",
      "layoutAlgorithm": "squarified",
      "allowDrillToNode": true,
      "dataLabels": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "levelIsConstant": false,
      "levels": [
        {
          "level": 1,
          "dataLabels": {
            "enabled": true
          },
          "borderWidth": 6,
          "borderColor": "#FFFFFF"
        }
      ],
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "id_0",
          "name": "Squadra1",
          "parentName": "Squadra1"
        },
        {
          "id": "id_0_0",
          "name": "ACC",
          "parent": "id_0",
          "parentName": "Squadra1",
          "scale": 0,
          "value": 1,
          "colorValue": 1.8117836848479765
        },
        {
          "id": "id_0_1",
          "name": "FEB",
          "parent": "id_0",
          "parentName": "Squadra1",
          "scale": 0,
          "value": 0,
          "colorValue": 5.48633338681632
        },
        {
          "id": "id_0_2",
          "name": "MAG",
          "parent": "id_0",
          "parentName": "Squadra1",
          "scale": 0,
          "value": 8,
          "colorValue": 3.4398769612396007
        },
        {
          "id": "id_0_3",
          "name": "PAM",
          "parent": "id_0",
          "parentName": "Squadra1",
          "scale": 0,
          "value": 7,
          "colorValue": 2.775814171372472
        },
        {
          "id": "id_1",
          "name": "Squadra2",
          "parentName": "Squadra2"
        },
        {
          "id": "id_1_0",
          "name": "ACC",
          "parent": "id_1",
          "parentName": "Squadra2",
          "scale": 10,
          "value": 13778,
          "colorValue": 13.595706940649173
        }
      ],
      "events": {},
      "_colorIndex": 0
    }
  ],
  "subtitle": {
    "text": "",
    "align": "",
    "style": {
      "color": "",
      "fontSize": "",
      "fontFamily": "",
      "fontStyle": "none",
      "textDecoration": "none",
      "fontWeight": "none"
    }
  },
  "title": {
    "text": "",
    "align": "",
    "style": {
      "color": "",
      "fontWeight": "none",
      "fontSize": "",
      "fontFamily": "",
      "fontStyle": "none",
      "textDecoration": "none"
    }
  },
  "lang": {
    "noData": ""
  },
  "noData": {
    "style": {
      "color": "",
      "fontSize": "",
      "fontFamily": "",
      "fontStyle": "none",
      "textDecoration": "none",
      "fontWeight": "none"
    },
    "position": {
      "align": "",
      "verticalAlign": "middle"
    }
  },
  "credits": {
    "enabled": false
  },
  "plotOptions": {
    "series": {
      "turboThreshold": 5000,
      "colorByPoint": false
    }
  }
}
```

Link of fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/3k5fmrut/2/

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve it is to set a smaller value for `Squadra2` and add an additional property with real value to point object that can be used in `tooltip.formatter` callback to present the real value in the tooltip. Check demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

data:

```
{
  "id": "id_1",
  "name": "Squadra2",
  "realValue": 13778,
  "parentName": "Squadra2"
}, {
  "id": "id_1_0",
  "name": "ACC",
  "parent": "id_1",
  "parentName": "Squadra2",
  "scale": 10,
  "value": 137.78,
  "colorValue": 13.595706940649173
}
```

tooltip.formatter:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    return this.point.realValue;
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/trz96fy7/

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own algorithm to build the treemap : [Highcharts treemap series](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/treemap)

You could choose an algorithm such that each element has a minimum width and height, and the biggest elements share the remaining space.